# Связать поле с таблицой в базе

Tags: база-данных, sql

Добрый день. Есть необходимость хранить данные по разным типам автомобилей - грузовые, легковые, специальные. У аждого типа автомобилей свой набор характеристик. Пришла в голову мысль объединить в одну таблицу общие свойства, а специфичные вынести в отдельную таблицу. И встал вопрос - как связать общую таблицу и таблицу специфичных свойств. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как логичнее реализовать такую схему и связать таблицы при условии, что новые типы автомобилей могут добавляться.

```
Общий список авто auto_list
+-------+-------+-------------+
|auto_id| doors |    price    |
+-------+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   4   |    10000    |
|   2   |   3   |    20000    |
|   3   |   2   |    10000    | 
+-------+-------+-------------+

Характеристики грузовых авто cargo_details
+-------+-------+-------------+
|auto_id| cargo |    wheels   |
+-------+-------+-------------+
|   2   |   4   |       6     |
+-------+-------+-------------+

Характеристики легковых авто passenger_details
+-------+-------+-------------+
|auto_id|passgrs|    fuel     |
+-------+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   4   |     92      |
|   3   |   6   |     95      |
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Таблицы связываются по auto_id, как это у вас и показано.
В общей таблице это PK, в спецификациях - FK.
Чтобы не создавать таблицы динамически, лучше предусмотреть заранее возможные типы автомобилей. Не думаю, что принципиально разных моделей будет много.
Подобная схема используется здесь: http://sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1
Да, не думаю, что цена является характеристирой типа. Это характеристика экземпляра.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Забыл написать, что ситуация вымышленная. В реальной ситуации речи идёт про другие объекты, просто хотелось упростить.
Буду разбираться, ещё раз благодарю. А то шальным делом сделал отдельную таблицу, для связи по типу, а в той таблице для связи держал название таблиц с деталями.